# Convert HTML Email into plain text, is it possible to add colour / style

Tags: asp.net, email, ascii

We currently have a bad situation where I need to change HTML Body content from a CMS and convert it to plain text so it can go into the body of an emailto.

```
        private static string StripHtmlToAscii(string mergeEmailBody)
    {
        var asciiEmailBody = mergeEmailBody;

        asciiEmailBody = asciiEmailBody.Replace("<br />", "%0D%0A").Replace("<br/>", "%0D%0A").Replace("+", "%20").Replace(" ", "%20").Replace("<p>", "").Replace("</p>", "%0D%0A%0D%0A").Replace("<br>", "%0D%0A");

        return asciiEmailBody;
    }
```

See above..

I am wondering is it possible to add style like bold or colour to a plain text email ?

Comment: "plain" means just that... "plain". nothing fancy, just text. no formatting (beyond spaces/tabs), no fonts, no colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, plain text is plain text, it will only accept text. The only way you can add colour is by sending an HTML email